# Login unsuccessful in 3 column table

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

I am trying to make login in c# the code is work properly on 2 column table but it does not work in 3 column table

```
 con.Open();
        sda = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * From login_faculty where uname = '" + uname.Text + "'and pass = '" + pass.Text + "' ", con);
        dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logined");
            name.Show();
            //current.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Can you give any more info on what it is that doesn't work? Are you seeing an error or anything like that?

Comment: the code does not go on if clause means it not satisfied the if condition and go on to else clause

Comment: the table have  3 columns with the name fac_id , uname and pass!

Comment: This code is extremely problematic on multiple levels. First is the fact that you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. Fix this before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ Second is that passwords should NEVER be stored in plain text. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: Couple of things I would do:  I would pull the condition out into a variable so you can see what it is being set to, and figure out why it is not equal to 1. Or, if you can only have unique combos of username and passwords, I would do a count on the rows in the data table, as if it is legit, the count will be 1, otherwise it is not legit and it should show your message box. Ideally, I would pass variables over to a stored proc, and return a BIT to see if it is legit.

Comment: You also need to wrap your connection in a USING statement. The way this is coded if there is an error after opening your connection it will get stuck open. And if only wanting to see a single scalar value from a query you would want to use ExecuteScalar instead of populating a datatable. Select ONLY the columns you need, not all of them.